# mysql user defined function - How to in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, user-defined-functions

How to create mysql user defined function with PHP, is that straight away passing whole create mysql UDF code in mysql_query function ?

Is there any php library or easy way to play with such things ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a query like any other. Send it with `mysql_query`.